# Como formatar campo com uma máscara definida em JAva

Tags: java, data, conversão

Como consigo formatar um campo int para string da forma a seguir:

`Campo int: 62016`

> campo final uma string que tem que ficar "062016"

Comment: Usando [leftPad](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#leftPad-java.lang.String-int-)

Comment: Valeu. Consegui fazer assim